# WebView and built in zoom control

Tags: android, webview, zooming, android-webview

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);

wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
setContentView(wv);
wv.loadData("<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>", null);
```

The zoom control only allows to zoom up to 7 clicks ( or levels ). Is there any other way, that I can zoom the text on the WebView more than 7 levels??? I need to zoom the text very big for accessibility purposes of my application.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.0+, use `setTextZoom()` on `WebSettings`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 which runs Android Version 3.2 and the setTextZoom() API call is only supported in 4.0 or above. :(

Comment: :) I wish I could... I have no idea when they are going to roll out the update.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a little troublesome but you should be able to grab the view surface from your webview as a bitmap and run it through a seperate view that would let you zoom down to the pixel scale.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a :

`public static int scalewebview;   // For example 220 (pretty normal size) or 460 (big)`

and then control the scale of your webview by using :

`webview.loadUrl(link);
webview.setInitialScale(scalewebview);
setContentView(webview);`